# jQuery error: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'using' in 100

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This code was working at one point, but now is throwing this error and I'm not really sure what it means. I googled it but it seems that the ones I found are close, but not exact to the issue that I am having.

error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'using' in 100

JS code:

```
    $('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset(100).top
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');

        //check to see if its a drop down button
        if(!$(this).hasClass("dropdown"))
        {
            if ( $(window).width() < 767){
                $('.navbar-toggle').click();
            }
        }
       event.preventDefault();
    });
```

This is the part that seems to be causing the issue:

```
   $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset(100).top
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
```

Comment: Can't see the error, comment out bits of the code to see what's causing it.

Comment: Have you checked anchor.href? Is it a valid #id?

Comment: Not sure what .offset(100) does either.

Comment: Are you using jQueryUI? You need that for the easing function `easeInOutExpo`.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/offset/ no arguments or object or function, not a number

Answer (score 0):

Check your `$($anchor.attr('href')).offset(100).top` value, or just use a static number instead of it, if it's ok, then the value must have some error about it.

Comment: when i put in a value it works, but the current line you mentioned above comes back with Unexpected token. I grabbed the demo from here as a starting point https://github.com/IronSummitMedia/startbootstrap/blob/gh-pages/templates/scrolling-nav/js/scrolling-nav.js

Comment: seems it's the (100) that is messing it up.. when I take that out.. everything is fine

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is ancient, but I just encountered a similar problem. If you look at the [jQuery documentation on `.offset(coordinates)`](https://api.jquery.com/offset/#offset2), you'll see it's looking not for *actual* coordinates, but rather an object containing coordinates:

> **coordinates**
>
> Type: [PlainObject](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#PlainObject)
>
> An object containing the properties `top` and `left`, which are numbers indicating the new top and left coordinates for the elements.

So if you do something like this:

```
$('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
    var $anchor = $(this);
    var myOffset = { top: "100px", left: "0px" };
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset(myOffset).top
    }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');

    //check to see if its a drop down button
    if(!$(this).hasClass("dropdown"))
    {
        if ( $(window).width() < 767){
            $('.navbar-toggle').click();
        }
    }
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

(note the `myOffset` variable and its use in the `.offset()` call)

You should get the desired result!